# Question about trace of matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, trace

In literature, I found the following identity. 
Unfortunately, I fail to see why this holds. 
Where does the trace of the matrix come from?
Any clarifications are highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace has the property of $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\bar{x})^TC^{-1}(x_n-\bar{x})&=\sum_{n=1}^N Tr((x_n-\bar{x})^TC^{-1}(x_n-\bar{x}))\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N Tr(C^{-1}(x_n-\bar{x})(x_n-\bar{x})^T)\\
&=Tr(C^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\bar{x})(x_n-\bar{x})^T)\\\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you clarify the first step, i.e. why is the LHS equal to the trace of itself?

Comment: the trace of a scalar is equal to the scalar itself. It is like $Tr(2)=2$.